# what is the better feature do we have in multiset that is not in vector?

Tags: c++, vector, set, containers, multiset

why we should use "multi set" (as we know "multi set" can keep repetitive key)

why we shouldn't use vector instead ?

is there any good feature in "multi set" that we don't have in vector ? (or other containers like vector)

Do you know any special usage for "multi set" ?

Comment: Access to the equivalent elements is O(log N), and the elements are automatically sorted (again with O(log N) insert time). Of course this is all pointless if the comparer checks for full equivalence - in that case, you'd keep a map<T, int> as a counter instead of storing the same object multiple times. The usual use case for a multiset is to store an object that contains both a key and some value, with the comparer just looking at the key part.

Comment: In a sense, a `multimap<K, V>` is essentially a `multiset<std::pair<K, V>>` with a comparer that just looks at `.first`. If the objects you want to store already have the key in them, by using a `multiset` instead of a `multimap` you can avoid its duplication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(moving/expanding from the comments)

> what is the better feature do we have in multiset that is not in vector?

The key feature is fast (O(log N)) lookup "equivalent" (according to the comparer) elements, plus implicit sorting according to the comparer (with O(log N) cost in insertion)).

(this plus the usual `set` features, such as O(1) removal (after O(log N) search) and references that are never invalidated)

---

`multiset` is quite a "niche" container; in 10+ years of writing C++ I don't think I ever used it (or seeing it being used, FWIW). Most probably, its very existence owes much to the `map`/`set` <=> `multimap`/`multiset` symmetry.

`set` is generally thought as "the container which does not allow duplicate elements", so having a set that allows duplicates apparently makes no sense at all. However, the actual point of `set` is to allow fast (O(log n)) lookup of objects *according to some criterion*, which crucially may not consider the *complete* content of the object.

Let's make a step back; it's helpful here to understand that `?map` is just a `?set` in disguise<sup>1</sup>. In particular, you can think of a `std::?map<K,V>` as a `std::?set<pair<const K,V>,KeyComp>`, where `KeyComp` is a comparer that only considers the `first` (=key) part of the pair<sup>2</sup> - which incidentally [is exactly what `std::?map::value_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/value_compare) is; you'll notice also that the type of `std::?map::value_type` is indeed `std::pair<const K, V>`.

So, `?map` is essentially a convenience over `?set` for the common case where you want to index values by some key that is not already "inside the value itself".

If instead the key is already stored inside the value - which is generally what happens when we are indexing existing data by some of its properties - a `?set` with a custom comparer can be used, thus avoiding the key replication of the key that would be required in a `?map`.

Let's consider an imaginary book database; you have a big `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Book>>` that contains all the book objects, and you want to index them by `author` and by `title` for quick lookup.

In this case, you can use a `multiset<Book *, CustomComp>` for each field you want to index; the custom comparer will implement a `<` operator that considers just a specific field of the pointed element.

When a new book is added you just need to add it to the `deque` and to all the indexes; when a book is removed you have to remove it from the `deque` and from the indexes. An edit requires to first remove it from the indexes, apply the changes and then re-add it (straight modification can lead to an inconsistent state of the `multiset` instances, because you may be changing the ordering relation between the stored objects "behind their back").

It's perfectly fine here that you have a set which allows duplicate elements: they are duplicate *only according to the comparer*, which just considers one field; it's perfectly normal to have multiple books by the same author, or different books with the same title. The point here is not "not allowing duplicates", it's "fast lookup by some key", exactly as if we were using a `multimap`, but without having to keep an extra copy of the key inside the indexes.

---

#### Notes

1. When I write `?set` or `?map` I'm talking about both the "regular" and "multi" variants. It's worth noting that the core of the discussion applies mostly in the same way even to the `unordered` counterparts, changing the comparer with the hash function.
2. Of course, when doing a lookup you have to provide a dummy `second` argument, and that's why using a `map` is more convenient.